# Bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else' not finding error

Tags: bash

I must be missing something, or some kind of error that just isn't sticking out to me. I'm sort of new to Bash, and I'm learning on a program assigned to me by work. I keep getting that error.

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "Argument is string"
    echo "Running string function"
    findProcessName()
else
    echo "Argument is number"
    echo "Running number function"
    findProcessID()
fi
```

**Answer:** parenthesis are not used when calling functions.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ is your friend

Comment: You don't use parentheses when calling functions

Comment: minimal example is your greatest friend.

Comment: More at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html

Comment: That was the issue I was having. Thank you @SeanBright

Comment: Please do not add "closed" in the title. Instead, post an answer indicating what was the issue and accept it.

Comment: The problem is the parenthesis (). Do not call function in bash like this: findProcessID(). Just do: findProcessID. Remove the ().